# Handling-Costraints in Genetic Algorithms: implementing the death penalty

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I would like to compare the "death penalty method" with other penalty methods proposed in the Genetic Algorithms' literature.

I'm using the R software, so I need to write the codes of these penalty methods.  I've finding lots of difficulties because I have not understood one thing about the death penalty function: how I have to handle the infeasible offsprings since the population size usually is fixed in genetic algorithms?

I mean, I understand that, in order to use appropriately the death penalty, I have to initialize the genetic algorithm with all feasible solutions. But even if I have all feasible solutions in the first population (t=0), I could have infeasible solutions in the next generation since the crossover and the mutations  are "blind" operators.

So, since the death penalty rejects all the infeasible solutions, then what happen?
Will the next generation have a population side smaller (original dim size - number of infeasible solutions) or I have to select more parents to put in the mating pool for reproduction until the next generation is composed by "original dim size" feasible offsprings or I have to try again the genetic operators until all the individuals in t+1 are feasible?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know R, but the theory of the death penalty implies that you should generate more offspring.

I would generate do the following pseudo-code (translate to R):

```
n=<desired_population_size>;
while (n>0) {
   generate n offspring;
   eliminate the non feasible ones
   add the feasible ones to the new generation
   n=<desired population size> - <current new generation population size>
}
```

The only problem with this loop is the risk that it may go on forever (if we never generate feasible solutions). Even though it is quite small, if you want to protect yourself from it, you can limit the number of iterations allowed in the while loop, using a simple counter.

There is a [pretty interesting article](http://opim.wharton.upenn.edu/~sok/papers/m/michalewicz-dont-kill-unfeasibles.pdf) on this by Michalewicz. Have a look.